# What was the first quantum error-correcting code?

Tags: quantum-information, history, quantum-computer

Is the Steane code the first quantum error-correcting code?

Comment: LPT: next time, show some research effort; you'll get a better response from the PSE community (upvotes, answers, etc). For example, you could read Steane's original paper, and check whether it mentions some previous code that serves to a similar purpose, etc.

Comment: You are right. This is my mistake. Thank you; it won't happen again.

Comment: Ah, no worries, it takes time to learn the mechanics of a community :-) I wish you the best of luck from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on the Wikipedia page on [Quantum Error Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction),

> Peter Shor first discovered this method of formulating a quantum error correcting code by storing the information of one qubit onto a highly entangled state of nine qubits.

Shor's work is from 1995, and Steane's from 1996.

Comment: I must have overseen this sentence on the Wikipedia page. Thank you for your help and time.